# Restangular - getList with parameters sent to server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, restangular, spring-restcontroller

I have method on server side:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<UserDTO> getAllUsers(@RequestParam(value = "groupId", required = false) Long groupId,
                                 @RequestParam(value = "pagination") Pagination pagination){
    // some stuff
}
```

And I try to send data from client side with `Restangular`:

```
function getUsers(filters){
    restService.all("users").getList(filters).then(function(users){
        $scope.data.users = users;
    });
}
// ....
getUsers({groupId: undefined, pagination: $scope.data.pagination});
```

Where `pagination` can be:

```
$scope.data = {
    // Other parameters
    pagination: {
        currentPage: 1,
        totalItems: 30,
        itemsPerPage: 5
    }
};
```

But I got:

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' 
to required type 'pagination.Pagination';
```

When I looked for `Request URL` I saw:

```
http://localhost:8080/skp/users?pagination=%7B%22currentPage%22:1,%22totalItems%22:30,%22itemsPerPage%22:5%7D
```

And `Query String Parameters` were:

```
pagination:{"currentPage":1,"totalItems":30,"itemsPerPage":5}
```

Which I hope should send pagination object to server side, but it tries to send string not object. Is there any idea how, with HTTP `GET` method and `getList` `Restangular` method send parameters not as `Query String`, which I think causes my problem? Or how make server side to treat it as `Pagination` object, not strings? Thank you very much for answers

Comment: your parameter pagination is going as a one parameter which is String. `pagination=%7B%22currentPage%22:1,%22totalItems%22:30,%22itemsPerPage%22:5%7D` . Instead of this, if you send these three parameters separately and have an input bean on server side where field names are same as parameter names, those will be auto populated with request parameters' values

Comment: @Amit.rk3 I do it and it seems like it works as I expect :) Please place your solution as normal answer, then I will be able to accept it

Comment: updated it in answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pagination=%7B%22currentPage%22:1,%22totalItems%22:30,%22itemsPerPage%22:5%7D
```

As stated in my comment this is one parameter with value as string. If you want an object or input bean to be populated at server side, you have to send three values inside pagination as three separate parameters. Keeping parameter and bean field names same to auto puplulate these fields